# Boomerang JS Not Including BW Results in Beacon

Tags: boomerang

I'm using boomerang to measure perceived client side loading statistics.  This works, but the Bandwidth and Latency plugin never sends it's results.  I can see it running in the console logs, but the beacon fires before it has even completed.

How can I get it to wait for the BW plugin to complete and include it's results in the beacon?

My Config:

```
BOOMR.init({
        beacon_url: "http://localhost/xxx/assets",
        BW: {
            base_url: "http://localhost/xxx/assets/images/",
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a new feature, but it turns out it could also be a bug.  Please post this on the boomerang issue tracker at https://github.com/lognormal/boomerang/issues so we can track it and post a fix.

I'll respond there as well as link to any commits that fix the issue.